# Help me ID snake

Tags: species-identification, species, herpetology

Could someone please tell me if this is a cotton mouth?  Found 2 on my back porch, one got away.

Location: Fayetteville, AR (USA) [Note: there are several ponds nearby]

[image]

Comment: Hi, for a better identification, please read the recommendation in the `species-identification` tag wiki [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification)

Answer (score -1):

The head does not look triangular or big enough to be a cottonmouth. The few times I have encountered cottonmouths in my yard they have been very calm , do not scurry off quickly. ID depends on where you are : here in E Tex it could be a green water snake or a yellow-belly water snake. Is there water nearby ? If not , maybe a rat snake. I did kill a cotton mouth once by mistake ; It looked like a green water snake that eats fish in my ponds. The greens disappear fast so I hit it before I could look at it closely. Too late I saw it was a cotton mouth ( which do not like small ponds so rarely come here).

Comment: I live in Fayetteville, AR. Yes there are several ponds nearby, which is where we usually see cotton mouths.  Rarely do they venture into our back yard.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a cottonmouth, it's *Nerodia rhombifer*, a diamondback water snake. It's nonvenomous and important for the ecosystem. Given that the water snakes compete with cottonmouths, it's important to not kill them to keep their populations high and not make room for cottonmouth populations to grow.

Comment: I had a diamond back water snake in my pond; He was much lighter in color , tan with brown "diamonds" .

Comment: Not certain why this post was downvoted given that it is the correct answer. Perhaps the downvoter doesn't believe in mutually-respectful dialogue. That's a shame.

Comment: Hi @ChrisMoore. Posts with citation notices generally attract downvotes (sometimes regardless of their correctness). I would advise providing a link or citation to a source that supports your answer. We're not looking for anecdotal comments, expert opinion, or short answers without explanations. We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context of why your answer is correct with citations/links to supporting evidence. [tag:species-identification] posts likewise benefit from providing images from reputable sources to further support your answer. Please revise. Thanks!